# How do you uppercase only certain parts of a single string that's in format "Town comma Initials"?

Tags: php, regex, ucfirst

I have a single location field where people can enter whatever they want, but generally they will enter something in the format of "Town, Initials".  So for example, these entries...

```
New york, Ny
columbia, sc
charleston
washington, DC
BISMARCK, ND
```

would ideally become...

```
New York, NY
Columbia, SC
Charleston
Washington, DC
Bismarck, ND
```

Obviously I can use `ucfirst()` on the string to handle the first character, but these are things I'm not sure how to do (if they can be done at all)...

- Capitalizing everything after a comma
- Lowercasing everything before the comma (aside from the first character)

Is this easily doable or do I need to use some sort of regex function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply chop it up and fix it.

```
<?php
$geo = 'New york, Ny
columbia, sc
charleston
washington, DC
BISMARCK, ND';
$geo = explode(PHP_EOL, $geo);

foreach ($geo as $str) {

    // chop
    $str = explode(',', $str);

    // fix
    echo 
    (!empty($str[0]) ? ucwords(strtolower(trim($str[0]))) : null).
    (!empty($str[1]) ? ', '.strtoupper(trim($str[1])) : null).PHP_EOL;
}
```

https://3v4l.org/ojl2M

Though you should not trust the user to enter the correct format. Instead find a huge list of all states and auto complete them in. Perhaps something like https://gist.github.com/maxrice/2776900 - then validate against it.